# Position off for view when using pushViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, pushviewcontroller

I have a view which is located inside a navigation controller which is inside a tab bar controller like this:

```
Tab Bar Controller

    Navigation Controller 

        View Controller
```

I have designed the layout of the View Controller in a xib. When I click the tab for the view the view is displayed correct. The view will be place within the navigation bar and the tab bar - it will not overflow.

But when I want to open the view programmatically - not via the tab bar - but with pushViewController [1] the view expands all the way to the outer bounds of the frame. The view will be over the status bar and below the tab bar.

I cannot find a solution to this. Does anybody have any ideas how to solve this?

[1]

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[MyViewController alloc] 
initWithStringAddress:"someIdUsedInController" animated:YES];
```

Comment: Are you adding your navigationContoller to the tabBarController?

Comment: Yes, I am. I am doing it in the MainWindow.xib. Is that the way to do it?

Comment: The navigationController is not recognizing the tab bar. How are you initializing the navigationController?